# Home printer / scanner - high quality images but occasional use

Tags: printer

I'm fed up with home inkjet printers. We don't print often and, whenever we wanted to, we'd find the ink had dried up. It's not much of an exaggeration to say that we ended up buying a new set of cartridges every time we had a printing batch to do.

So I'd resolved to get a laser printer. But they're all huge and we have limited space. And mostly we print images and they need to be high quality - and I think I'm right in saying that laser printers are not ideal for this?

Now I'm in a quandary. There are so many printers, it's hard to find or search on their dimensions and after having so many bad experiences, I simply don't trust the manufacturers. I'd be willing to spend quite a lot of money - £300 or so - to get a printer I could rely on.

Here's what I need:
- Can be relied on to work after 1-2 months without use
- No more than 39cm deep
- high print quality
- (nice to have, not essential) paper casette, duplex

What printer can I trust?

Comment: "and I think I'm right in saying that laser printers are not ideal for this?" [Depends on your usage scenario (Photos vs Text)](https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/inkjet-vs-laser-printers-which-is-better-for-home-use-176198). Also I've never heard of ink drying up in a printer cartridge, that just sounds like a defective printer.

Comment: @BennettYeo  I had at least 5 inkjet printers(different models,brands,etc), in the past, have the ink in the nozzles dry up and prevent ink from flowing.  Then using water/alcohol to clear them was a real pain.  Since I got a color laser I have none of those issues.  I too only print once every few months.

Comment: @BennettYeo  I would, but the HP M551dn is far beyond the 300 budget.

Comment: HP Color LaserJet Enterprise M553n is currently $479 (usd) on hp.com, it is non-duplex.  The duplex version is $679